# MacOS High Sierra/Mojave cannot connect to it from any lan devices

Tags: networking, mac, ssh, proxy, android

My problem is the following: I have my mac book pro (192.168.1.7) currently on Mojave beta on the same network as my android device (192.168.1.44). I would like to setup my android's proxy to my mac (to Charles or BurpSuite). The problem is that running services on my mac (httpd, ssh, proxy) are not accessible from my local network and I don't understand why. 
Ex: if I try to hit http://192.168.1.7 (my Mac) from my android's browser, the request will time out, same with ssh and of course (the main problem) with the proxy.

I already tried to configure/disable the firewall, edit the /etc/pf.conf, etc but nothing changed. Services still accessible locally (localhost or mymac.local) but not accessible to my others devices on the network.

I saw that requests hit my mac well (from android by ex) because I can see incoming packets when running tcpdump.

I have no more idea to debug this problem. Thanks for the help !

PS: I don't think mojave is the problem because it never worked too on high sierra before.